# How to read temperature using arduino uno board with PT100 RTD sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

I am new to arduino programming. And almost inexperienced.

I am looking to program my arduino Uno board to read 2/3/4 wire configuration of PT100 RTD sensor (in accuracy levels of atleast 0.5°C). The temperature range is 0 to 400°C and -50 to 100°C.

Since I am totally new to this field I would appreciate a rather descriptive information with circuits and images and code.

I have researched a lot on the subject, but couldn't get anything useful or substantial to solve my problem.

Moreover, I cannot use thermistor or any IC to read the temperatures as the machine on which the RTD is installed has PIDs, but I would like to create a datalogger that can fetch temperatures on computer itself.

Comment: You can get ICs which can be used for these sensors, wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: I am unable to use ICs as already we are using RTDs with PID controllers to control the temperature. I have to use these existing RTDs to get the temperature readings otherwise there might be variation in the temperature readings of RTD and IC. Moreover, we have applications where we require temperature readings of about 400°C with an accuracy of +/- 0.5°C. I doubt that there exists any ICs that can handle such precision and temperature range.

Comment: how are the RTDs connected then at the moment

Comment: A MAX31865 can handle -200°C to 500°C. Are you concerned about the IC being exposed to temperatures?

Comment: Actually, the RTDs are installed on a cable extruder having holes to insert the RTD into them. The temperature currently are being read through PID controllers. And yes I am concerned about having the IC damaged. Moreover, how am I supposed to insert the ICs in those tiny holes in the extruder barrel?

Comment: I'd llike to clear up a slight misunderstanding: The PT100 RTD is the SENSOR and the MAX31865 is the SENSOR AMPLIFIER, SIGNAL CONDITIONER and A/D CONVERTER. As such, the MAX31865 is NOT subjected to extreme temperaturas as it is NOT the sensor. HTH.

Comment: No need to shout. I was actually pointing out the range that the IC works with, i.e. the resistive output of the RTD. The operating is -65  to 150, in my comments I never stated it was the operating temperature. Also make a worth while contribution to the forum and give answers or ask questions so you can get rep to comment rather than put up useless answers like this.